# Javascript call trace using debugging tool like firedbug

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, trace

i saw a website thats doing something unique on the client side only and am trying to imitate it.
but i need to know which functions are being called, and what started the call, since i observer that most of the things done is based on clicking and typing, as it has a lot of JavaScript loaded.

does any tool gives you this information for example firebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebug gives you ability to see the javascript code, you can even step through it.  the script tab of firebug should give you what your looking for.

http://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: hello, i know you can use firebug, but how?

Comment: Open firebug, click the script tab and you can choose what javascript file you want to debug.  You can click in the left nav (line numbers) to add a break point. Check out the firebug documentation to find specific uses: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page